# Pause/Play video in Slick slider

Tags: html5-video, slick.js

I have a Slick slider with some images and some html5 videos.
I have managed to make the Prev/Next arrows work: if I click on the arrows the slider goes to the next video (it plays automatically) and the previous one is paused.

Now I've added a button to pause/play the current video, but I can't find a way to make it work properly. The button works only the first time a video is played. If I change slide and go back to the same video I am not able to pause it anymore.

```
$('.sliderVideo').slick({
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
arrows: true,
fade: true,
dots: true,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 1000,
adaptiveHeight: true,
pauseOnHover:false,
cssEase: 'linear'});


$('.sliderVideo').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){    
  $("video").each(function(){
    $(this).get(0).pause();
  });
});


$('.sliderVideo').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
var vid = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).find('video');
if (vid.length > 0) {
    $('.sliderVideo').slick('slickPause');
    $(vid).get(0).play();


    var MyPlayButton = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).find('.play-button');
    //var MyPlayButton = $('.play-button');

        MyPlayButton.on('click', function () {

        if ($(vid).get(0).paused) {         
            $(vid).get(0).play();
            console.log('play');
        } else {
            $(vid).get(0).pause();
            console.log('paused');
        }
        return false;
    }); 
}   
});

$('video').on('ended',function(){           
$('.sliderVideo').slick('slickPlay');});
```

I would really appreciate your help.

I've created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8ds3Lrxm/22/

Answer (score 0):

OK, fixed this way:

```
var MyPlayButton = null;

$('.sliderVideo').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

if (null !== MyPlayButton) {
    MyPlayButton.off('click');
}

$("video").each(function(){
    $(this).get(0).pause();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way (keeping it simple is best)
this way we reset the video whenever we start playing it...

```
$('#slider_id').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    // pause old video (better performance)
    var old_vid = $('#slider_id .slide:eq('+currentSlide+')').find('video');
    $(old_vid).get(0).pause();


    // play current video from start
    var cur_vid = $('#slider_id .slide:eq('+nextSlide+')').find('video');
    $(cur_vid).get(0).currentTime = 0;
    $(cur_vid).get(0).play();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.video_banner_slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  
   console.log(currentSlide);
   $("video").each(function(){
       $(this).get(0).pause();
     });

});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.